# app update crashes just after default.png is showed

Tags: iphone, distribution, profile

I'd like to test the new version of my app as an update of my former version. So I installed the older version from Appstore.

Here's my problem :
when I try to deploy the new version on my device (iphone 3G) : build is ok, install seems ok but when the app launches there's only the default.png that shows 1 second before everything crashes.
In Organizer - console I can see the following errors :

```
<Error>: entitlement 'keychain-access-groups' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
<Error>: entitlement 'application-identifier' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
<Warning>: Killing <SBApplication: 0x9aa5650> XXXXXX  activate:  deactivate:  for app installation
...
UIKitApplication:AGLFRX2P2[0x1878][1034]) <Error>: (UIKitApplication:XXXXXX2[0x1878]) posix_spawn("/var/mobile/Applications/97DFB148-4C95-4DB4-AAA7-19DFE81C0BE1/XXXXXX.app/XXXXXX", ...): Permission denied
...
```

if I do the same thing on my iphone without the older version installed (or the older version deployed by myself from xCode) , eveything works well !

Does it mean i can't install an update of my app with my developer profile when the app installed on the device was built with my distribution profile ?

Thank you so much for your help !

info :
I just updated xCode to the last version 3.2.3.
I also updated my iPhone 3G to OS4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system itself appears to display the default.png while the app loads. The default.png image can show even if the app crashes immediately.

In this case, you are using the old distribution profile for new application build and the identity hash of the old code in the old profile does not match the identity hash of the new code.

You can't overwrite a store installed app with a dev profile. The profiles exist precisely to keep new code from being inserted into an app after it has been installed.

I'm pretty sure you will need to test the upgrade process using the old version installed with a developers profile. Nothing I know of in the developer's tools allows you to override a deployment profile.